# Unable to draw on top of bitmap to which i set BG from resource

Tags: android, background, bitmap, drawing, drawable

I am trying to set a background ti bitmap and then to be able to draw on top of it so later i will be able to save the bitmap to gallery.

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    paint.setStrokeWidth(changeWidth());
        if (bitmap == null)
               {            
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);                   
               }

              //Boolean parameters allowing to change bg in case preference changed
            if(prefs_grid)
                {
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.grid_view);

                }
            if(prefs_ruler)
                {
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.rulers_view);
                }


            canvas = new Canvas();
            try {
                canvas.setBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.w("setBitmap", "unable to set Bitmap");
            }
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
}
```

This is where i change the bitmap. The bitmap does change but the line:
  canvas.setBitmap(bitmap); 
doesn't work and i cant get it why?
Can someone consult me on this issue.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding this

```
canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
```

// try locking the canvas for exclusive pixel editing

// in the surface

Comment: i get the next error
: surfaceHolder cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: you dont have a surface holder thats why ok just refer  http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/07/android-game-development-measuring-fps.html from the start you will get an idea

Comment: there may be such as using set as background instead (now you are not setting as BG but that wont be the best method

Comment: I tried that earlier and it worked but when i save i am saving the i am saving the bitmap. and the bitmap doesn't include the background. Is there a way to add the view and the bitmap to the same picture which i am saving togallery?

Comment: then its better you use surface holder and canvas with lock canvas method so that you can edit that pixel on the surface